# URL masking in html

Tags: html, url, frame, url-masking

I have masked a URL in my html page as follows:

```
<head>
<base href="http://www.abc.com" />
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="">
<TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<FRAMESET ROWS="100%,*" frameborder="no" framespacing=0 border=0>
<FRAME SRC="https://www.xyz.com/login.htm" NAME="mainwindow" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></FRAME>
</FRAMESET>
<NOFRAMES>
</head>
```

The `https://www.xyz.com/login.htm` is an outsourced link and I do not have access to the source code. When the user clicks the `login button` on the page, the user is successfully logged in. On login a separate page is loaded `user.htm`. However, due to the masking applied (above), I see the masked URL even after login. I would like to view the original url once the user logs in. Can I prevent that?

EDIT: I got access to the login.htm file. It is now placed on my server. This file contains the login button which is not really a button but an image:

```
<input target="_top" type="image"  src="images/login-submit.png" align="middle" value="Connect" name="Connect">
```

Adding target="_top" to the button is not helping. How can I break out of the frame on clicking `connect`. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the content is on another origin, you can't detect when the user has logged in from the frame page, so you can't do anything in response to the user logging in.

Since you have no access to `login.htm` (and presumably `user.htm`) you can't add `target="_top"` there either.

So no, you can't prevent it.

Comment: If the original url does not show on the `user.htm` page, I am unable to click on anything on that (`user.htm`) page. Will adding `target="_top"` solve the issue? Where does this has to be placed in `user.htm`?

Comment: I got access to the `login.htm` file. It is now placed on my server. This file contains the `login button` which is not really a button but an image:
`<input target="_top" type="image"  src="images/login-submit.png" align="middle" value="Connect" name="Connect">`
Adding `target="_top"` to the button is not helping. Any pointers?

Comment: The target attribute goes on the form, not the button.